# Как записать код всей html страницы в переменную?

Tags: php

Есть какой-либо документ в Интернете. Например, вот:

`http://adindex.ru/catalogue/reclama_services/full_cycle`

Требуется записать в переменную $xxx весь HTML код этой страницы. Благодарю заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xxx = file_get_contents('http://adindex.ru/catalogue/reclama_services/full_cycle');
```

Comment: Да, это оно, благодарю!